# C# configSections "Sections must only appear once per config file."

Tags: c#, configsection

I want to create a "List" of `clientUsers` that contains many of `clientUser`

```
 <configuration>
        <configSections>
          <sectionGroup name="clientUsers">
            <section name="clientUser" type="System.Configuration.NameValueFileSectionHandler" />
          </sectionGroup>
        </configSections>

        <clientUsers>
            <!-- user number 1  -->
            <clientUser>
              <add key="id"       value="1" />
              <add key="userName" value="someuser" />
              <add key="password" value="test" />
              <add key="IPs"      value="1,2,3" />
            </clientUser>

            <!-- user number 2  -->
            <clientUser>
              <add key="id"       value="2" />
              <add key="userName" value="avi2" />
              <add key="password" value="test" />
              <add key="IPs"      value="1,2,3" />
            </clientUser>
   </clientUsers>
```

Why do i get this error:

> > Sections must only appear once per config file.  See the help topic  for exceptions.

How do I create a list of `clientUser`

Comment: The comments in your XML are actually written like that in your file? If they are, change // for <!-- comment -->

Comment: You are getting the error for exactly the reason it says.  **ClientUser** is only allowed to be in the file once.

Comment: @Ramhound - Do you have any idea how annoying is your comment ??? I am asking how to create a list of ClientUser.

Comment: I think there are similar questions asked already. Check the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710449/accessing-a-custom-configuration-section-in-net). He did it with a custom configuration handler.

Comment: Thanks but it is not the same... see my structure, it is different. thanks

Comment: @SexyMF: yes, that's what you need. You will not be able to have exactly that structure in your config file, but you will only need to add a node. Otherwise, remove the sectionGroup, which is not mandatory, and call your configSection `clientUsers`, and have it contain sever `clientUser` objects.

Comment: @SexyMF I guess you have to change your structure. I looked over his answer and I think it's everything you need to solve your issue.

Comment: You *did* ask why you got the error.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for ConfigurationElementCollection class under System.Configuration MSDN Link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationelementcollection.aspx

There is also a tutoial on [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CustomConfigurationSectio.aspx)

A short snippet from the codeproject site

```
public class ShiSettingCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
   {
      public ShiSettingElements this[int index]
      {
         get
         {
            return base.BaseGet(index) as ShiSettingElements;
         }
         set
         {
            if (base.BaseGet(index) != null)
            {
               base.BaseRemoveAt(index);
            }
            this.BaseAdd(index, value);
         }
      }
      protected override System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
      {
         return new ShiSettingElements();
      }

      protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
      {
         return ((ShiSettingElements)element).Key;
      }
   }
```